Plugin [id: 'kotlin-android'] was not found in any of the following sources:
I have this problem when I was trying to run my newly created flutter project
[I tried modifying my android/app/build.gradle file with this (image 1)I also tried to modify the root build.gradle file as shown in image 2. I am still unable to build and run my flutter application.](https://i.sstatic.net/Awj7gY8J.png)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
